# jQuery Mobile Submit AJAX Form without redirect

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery-mobile

I have a form created with jQuery Mobile. As we know jquery mobile form as default is sending request with ajax. But what i think not correct is why after the ajax is send, the page is still redirected to action page?

please see live example here: http://puredataconsulting.com/purwa/liquorworks/form/index.php

After form submitted, jquery send post via AJAX to http://puredataconsulting.com/purwa/liquorworks/form/inc/store-address.php

But after send ajax, why the page still redirected to http://puredataconsulting.com/purwa/liquorworks/form/inc/store-address.php ??

I didn't want jquery to redirect?
how to do it?